# Select * from table where date selected is between

Tags: sql, t-sql

i trying to build the following query to `select * from table` where the `minDate` is `03-02-2014` and the `maxDate` is `01-03-2014`

but something i missing.

hope that someone can help me with this.

```
SELECT * From table Where 
SUBSTRING(mydate, 1, 10) >= REPLACE('03-02-2014','-','/') AND 
SUBSTRING(mydate, 1, 10) <= REPLACE('01-03-2014','-','/')
```

Note:
My Date column is of type varchar with a value like this --> 03/02/2014 18:13:16

im working in sql server management studio (t-sql)

Comment: You should convert the column to a date before comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, it seems that the `mydate` column of your table is in the British format.
Read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) about date conversion in SQL SERVER to understand more about date conversions.
Also updated my answer with the date conversions for this format.

Try something like

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(mydate, 1, 10), 103) >= CONVERT(DATE, '03/02/2014', 103)
    AND CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(mydate, 1, 10), 103) <= CONVERT(DATE, '01/03/2014', 103)
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: my format is like this: 27/02/2014 16:56:09  ... and also continued with conversion failed

Comment: I meant is it 'mm/dd/yyyy' or 'dd/mm/yyyy'. But I think it is dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like:

```
Select * From Table 
Where CONVERT( Datetime, mydate ,110 ) between CONVERT( Datetime, @min ,110 ) and between CONVERT( Datetime, @max ,110 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have SSMS available right now, but for a quick try you might try this

```
SELECT * From table Where 
CAST( SUBSTRING(mydate, 1, 10) as date) BETWEEN CAST( SUBSTRING('START DATE', 1, 10) as date)
AND CAST( SUBSTRING('END DATE', 1, 10) as date)
```